# Querying Transitive Relations

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm playing with SPARQL and trying to query all direct and indirect influences of Stephen King from dbpedia, but I can't get the query working.

I saw that one can normally use "+" to query transitive relations, but the query I wrote return exactly the same as a query that ignores transitive relations. Here is what I've tried: [query-transitive-influencedBy](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%3Fo%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%3AStephen_King%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FinfluencedBy%3E%2B%20%3Fo%0D%0A%7D)

Another thing that I've tried which works (at least partially) is:
[query-transitive-influencedBy-v2](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%3FstephensDirectInfluencer%20%3FstephensIndirectInfluencer%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%3AStephen_King%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FinfluencedBy%3E%20%3FstephensDirectInfluencer%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3FstephensDirectInfluencer%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FinfluencedBy%3E%20%3FstephensIndirectInfluencer%20.%0D%0A%7D). This works, however it has two drawbacks: 1. Returns people that have influenced Stephen King, but also have the influencedBy relation themselves. And by doing this reduces the total count of data returned.
2. Returns data for only direct and indirect influencers for one level.

What would be the correct way to query such data?

Comment: Your first query works for me on http://dbpedia.org/sparql instead of the SNORQL interface.

Comment: Indeed it works correctly. That's very odd because both interfaces should in theory return the same thing because I think they use the same endpoint.

Comment: I agree with you, different user interfaces should return the same result. Maybe you can report this as bug, although I'm not sure where.

Comment: Openlink reported this is now fixed, can you check again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an encoding issue in the old http://dbpedia.org/snorql which caused the + to be filtered out. I have fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick, the issue seems to be fixed now. The query returns same result as the other endpoint.